# Usar !important no CSS aplicado com Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho um código em Jquery, e gostaria de aplicar o `!important` no CSS, conforme abaixo:

```
$('.prodMenor:eq(6)').css('margin-right','0!important');
```

Porém, do jeito que fiz não está funcionando, há outra forma?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Consegui uma solução alternativa:***

**CSS:**

```
.imp{margin-right: 0!important}
```

**Jquery:**

```
    $('.prodMenor:eq(6)').addClass('imp');
```

Resolveu! :)